# Regex_match in IF case

Tags: regex, database, analysis, modeling, alteryx

I want to make a Alteryx end-user prompt that will allow him to enter date into the data rows.
The trick is that only first day of month is accepted in below format:

"mm/d/yyyy" (01/1/2017, 12/1/2018)

Unfortunately whenever I enter text, or other format (JAN-1-2016 etc) the warning prompt accepts it and enters the value into rows.

```
IsEmpty([#1])
or 
IIF(regex_match([#1],"(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/[12]\d{3}"),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I modified the regexp and swapped 1 with 0 at the end of IIF.
This will force end-user to enter only first day of month in one format: mm/d/yyyy

```
IsEmpty([#1])
or 
IIF(regex_match([#1],"(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([1]|[12]\d|3[01])\/[12]\d{3}"),0,1)
```